# How to apply gradient coloring to Cuboid

Tags: graphics3d, color

I would like to apply gradient coloring lengthwise to a Cuboid. The coloring can be within the volume or one of its long faces. I'm not sure which would look better. Here's what I have so far:

```
Graphics3D[{
EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.0015], Black}],
GrayLevel[0.8, 0.4],
Opacity[0.8],
Cuboid[{-6, -50, -4}, {6, 70, 3}, 
VertexColors -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]],
}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.8, 0.3}, 
ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

My failed attempt was to use VertexColoring but that doesn't work with Cuboid. I would prefer to stay with Cuboid.

Comment: `Cuboid[]` does not support `VertexColors`; you'll need to use `Polygon[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @JM points out, you can't use `VertexColors` with `Cuboid`, only `Polygon`, `Line`, `Tube`, `Point`, and `GraphicsComplex` (from the `VertexColors` documentation). `GraphicsComplex` is probably what you want here.

```
vertices = Tuples[Transpose[{{-6, -50, -4}, {6, 70, 3}}]];
vc = ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#] & /@ {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}; 
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.0015], Black}], GrayLevel[0.8, 0.4],
   Opacity[0.8], 
  GraphicsComplex[vertices, 
   Polygon[{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 6, 2, 
      4}, {8, 7, 5, 6}, {8, 7, 3, 4}}], VertexColors -> vc]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.8, 0.3}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

So the colouring is down the length on all sides. You can of course mess around with how I've set the colours to the vertices in `vc`.

If, instead, you just want the colouring on one face, you can draw that polygon separately:

```
vertices = Tuples[Transpose[{{-6, -50, -4}, {6, 70, 3}}]];
vc = ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#] & /@ {1, 1, 0, 0};
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.0015], Black}], GrayLevel[0.8, 0.4],
   Opacity[0.8], 
  GraphicsComplex[vertices, 
   Polygon[{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 5, 
      6}, {8, 7, 3, 4}}]], 
  Polygon[vertices[[{4, 8, 6, 2}]], VertexColors -> vc]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.8, 0.3}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: I run your code but mine appears opaque. I am using 11.0 student version.

Comment: I have 10.4. I can't find anything on SE or Google about an `Opacity` bug in 11. Does changing the value affect anything at all?

Comment: No, same thing no matter what I set for Opacity.

Comment: That's weird. Sorry about that. There's not much I can do from this end, but you could play around with `Opacity` in some other `Graphics3D` constructions and see if you can find what breaks it. Then post another question specifically about this issue.